# Is there any way to save progress mid-area?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I am having ridiculous fun with Chantelise, but I find that I die an awful lot. I dislike having to play areas over and over - is there any way I can save partway, like checkpoints or what have you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to save in the middle of an area in the game. This is part of the game's action-RPG stylings, and replaying areas will be necessary as you progress through it.

Comment: :( Will keep trying, then. I WILL SUCCEED!